# Webservice returns recordset or converting JSON to recordset?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, vb6

Retrofitting a legacy VB6 application to send webrequests to an API that returns mainframe data. The VB6 app requires a recordset as a return method for the function I'm looking to replace with the webservice call.

I've managed to get the API to return a JSON payload of all of the relevant records, but I'm not finding good ways to convert JSON into a recordset on the VB6 end. Is there a way to either: Pass a recordset from the C#/.NET API or convert JSON to a recordset on the VB6 end?

Comment: You would find better support for xml than json in VB6, maybe consider support both result types in the API.

Comment: IMHO VB6-JSON is a good choice: http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

Comment: @deblocker Can that parse the JSON into a recordset?

Comment: Once you have a JSON parser, you don't need a RS anymore. I understand that a plug-in module would be ideal, but I believe also that looping over an array is the same as looping over a RS. If you can't touch the VB6 legacy app, just a small wrapper class should do the trick. A RS can be created also on the fly with the needed fields.

Comment: OH, I'm reading just now your previous question... you posted a link to the same JSON parser... amazing! So...to answer your above Q, i believe that creating a JSON from a RS is trivial, because there is a well-defined standard and naming convention - but you only can get from your JSON a RS ;-)

Comment: That's my issue is that this recordset gets called time and time again throughout a spiderweb of interconnected legacy programs. So having the data in JSON doesn't help me because the recordset variable gets referenced in 50 other locations. I'm out of ideas...